# GitHub Repo for Website Rebuild

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repo for a website I built a few years ago. I'm about to completely rebuild that website, and I have a question about best practices. Should I create a new repository for the new version of the site or use a combination of branches and tags within the current repository? Any further explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd first recommend creating `develop` and `master` branches from your old site's latest commit if you don't already have those.
2. Then, tag the latest `master` commit to mark the end of development on your old site.
3. Do all new site development in branches from `develop` with names like `feature/`, `bugfix/` or `hotfix/`, depending on the type of work you're completing in that branch.
4. When you're ready to release a new version of your site, merge `develop` back into `master` with a release tag for the newly-completed version.

[See the `git-flow` pages for a reliable set of practices.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)